# Formatting Excel sheet row color based on a cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-interop

i have a grid with column of orders numbers,
with this columns i check excels file,
if specific cell in the excel file is empty - the row will be red else is will be green.
but i dont why everythis is getting the red color.
this is my code:

```
GridView View = gridView2 as GridView;
for (int i = 0; i <= gridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    string status = (string)View.GetRowCellValue(i, View.Columns[0]);
    if (File.Exists(@"I:\OPTIMIZER\" + status + @"_הזמנת_רכש_חומרים.xls"))
    {
        //Create an excel application object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelAppObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelAppObj.DisplayAlerts = false;

        //Open the excel work book
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelAppObj.Workbooks.Open(@"I:\OPTIMIZER\" + status + @"_הזמנת_רכש_חומרים.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", false,
                                                                                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                                                                                      true, false, 0, false, false);

        //Get the first sheet of the selected work book
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        var cellValue = (string)(worksheet.Cells[10, 5] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;

        if (cellValue != null)
        {
            View.Appearance.Row.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            View.Appearance.Row.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        else
        {
            View.Appearance.Row.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
            View.Appearance.Row.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        workBook.Close(false);
        excelAppObj.Quit();
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your cell value maybe is empty string instead of null, try to use this ` if (cellValue == null || cellValue == ""){ //red } else { //green }`

Comment: @aswzen i check it, now everything is red ..

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to look at what cell value actually is rather than guessing ?

Comment: @CaiusJard i debug now and i saw that every time all the grid is colored, once red once green based on the value that i get, how to draw only the row?

Comment: You are looking for Conditional formatting.  [This post](https://jira.visma.com/browse/EC-34236) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the color value to entire grid view.

Please use the specific ROW to which this cell belongs and then set that specific ROW's color property. You already have the specific ROW in which the cell value may be null. Use 'i' to get the specific row from grid and set the color.

Here you go...hopefully this works.

```js
                    GridViewRow gvCurrentRow = (GridViewRow)gridView2.Controls[0].Controls[i];
if (cellValue != null)
                  {
  gvCurrentRow.BackColor = //set it to whatever you want
 gvCurrentRow.ForeColor = //set it to whatever you want

}
else
{
  gvCurrentRow.BackColor = //set it to whatever you want
                    gvCurrentRow.ForeColor = //set it to whatever you want

}
```

Comment: yes, this is what i need, but i done know what to write. can you please edit my code?

Comment: Added code sample to get the current row. Hope this helps